# How can i fix fragment overlapping?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have create only one fragment dynamically in Activity and add data to fragment. When i changed my data fragment again created. When i want to go back to activity they will display first previous data then go Main Activity when i press back button. How to resolve this issue when i press back button they go only main activity not previous data.

```
 SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment(MainActivity.this);
                searchFragment.setArguments(extra);
                fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myFragmwent_layout,searchFragment,"first");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

```
 SearchFragment searchFragment = (SearchFragment) 
 manager.findFragmentByTag("first");
                fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                if (searchFragment!=null){
                    fragmentTransaction.remove(searchFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
```

Search Fragment Class

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        if (getArguments()!=null){
            keyword = getArguments().getString("keyword");
        }
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_Frag);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        categoryItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        sQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url+keyword,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String creatorName = data.getString("name");
                                String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
                                String articleId = data.getString("article_id");
                                categoryItemArrayList.add(new CategoryItem(imageUrl, creatorName, articleId));
                            }
                            mCustomadapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), categoryItemArrayList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCustomadapter);
                            mCustomadapter.setOnItemClickListener(SearchFragment.this);
                            mCustomadapter.updateData();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "data not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        sQueue.add(arrayRequest);

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use replace instead of add in your case

```
SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment(MainActivity.this);
                searchFragment.setArguments(extra);
                fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragmwent_layout,searchFragment,"first");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Please give click on tick mark so it will turn in to green. The tick mark will be under Up and down arrow

Comment: Yes i'll do i have an internet problem that's why not show green don't worry bro i'll do check it out

Answer (score 1):

`FragmentTransaction.add()` adds multiple fragments to a container and they will be layered one on top of the other. If your fragments have transparent backgrounds you will see this effect and will be able to interact with the multiple fragments at the same time.

If you use `FragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment)` it will remove any fragments that are already in the container and add your new one to the same container.

So you need to modify your code and use `fragmentTransaction.replace` instead of `fragmentTrasaction.add`

```
SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment(MainActivity.this);
searchFragment.setArguments(extra);
fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragmwent_layout,searchFragment,"first");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```